# Setting default text for a combo box

Tags: c#, silverlight, text, combobox, default

I'm wondering if there is a way in silverlight to set a placeholder value for a combo box.

The behavior I wish to achieve is such that when the combo box has no selection, a placeholder value is shown.

This value shouldn't be displayed when the user clicks to open the list of values, and if the selected index is cleared, the placeholder value is shown again.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display default text "--Select Team --" in combo box on pageload in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426050/how-to-display-default-text-select-team-in-combo-box-on-pageload-in-wpf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this [How to display default text "--Select Team --" in combo box on pageload in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426050/how-to-display-default-text-select-team-in-combo-box-on-pageload-in-wpf) and this [Silverlight 4 ComboBox - Binding to Nullable data (tried TargetNullValue but not working as expected)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639751/silverlight-4-combobox-binding-to-nullable-data-tried-targetnullvalue-but-not)