# ms silverlight blend sketchflow - default text in combobox

Tags: silverlight, combobox, blend, sketchflow

I'd like to get the default text in a combo box to show "Select Team...."

Like this in WPF

[Setting default text for a combo box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601421/setting-default-text-for-a-combo-box)

But in sketchflow.

How can I do this?

Thanks

it is a sliverlight project.  my xaml reads:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="SchoolsLoginScreens.Screen_2"
Width="640" Height="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
<ComboBox Height="61.256" Width="136.569" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" Text="-- Select Team --"/>
</Grid>
```

It says that IsEditable does not have a setter.  But this appears to work in WPF project like the examples above.

Answer (score 0):

SketchFlow projects are WPF or SL projects (depending what you chose when you created the project) so any answers you find for WPF/SL should apply.

Comment: Sorry I'm a  stackoverflow-newbie.   I found some code, but it wouldn't fit in this comments box, so I edited question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/1218ea61-350a-4c93-9e07-cda1a2f42bb8/combo-box-questions?forum=blend) to help me. Essentially, you just have to add at least one item to the combo box (right-click, add ComboBoxItem) then look at the Common properties while the control is selected and you will see a field called "SelectIndex" that is currently set to -1. Just change this to 0 to select the first item in your list.